# Cannot click button inside a list (ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having a problem with a button inside a list. The list is being built with `ng-repeat`. I'm trying to create a simple web app for creating tasks. Given the following code,
I can't click the button which is supposed to show the task description (the one with the gear). Thank you in advance.

HTML:

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Tasks List</title>

    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <!-- un-comment this code to enable service worker
    <script>
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js')
          .then(() => console.log('service worker installed'))
          .catch(err => console.log('Error', err));
      }
    </script>-->

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>





  <body ng-app="todo" ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
        <h1 class="title">Tasks</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
        <div class="list list-inset">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" name="list" placeholder="Task Name" ng-model="task">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="description">
          </label>
        </div>

        <button class ="button button-dark right" ng-click="add(task,description)">Add</button>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col"></div>
            <div class="col col-50">

              <ion-list show-delete="1==1" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                <ion-item>
                  {{task.taskname}}
                    <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="delete(task)"></ion-delete-button>
                    <button ng-click="task.selected=!task.selected" class="btn button icon ion-gear-a"></button>
                </ion-item>

               <div class="item item-divider" ng-show="task.selected">
                {{task.description}}
               </div>
              </ion-list>
            </div>
          </div>



      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope, $ionicModal){
  $scope.tasks=[
{
  taskname: 'Hi',
  description:'I am a description',
  selected: false
},
{
  taskname:'Hello',
  description:'I am another description',
  selected: false
},
{
  taskname: '123',
  description:'I am another description',
  selected: false
},
{
  taskname: '456',
  description:'I am another description',
  selected: false
},
{
  taskname: '789',
  description:'I am another description',
  selected: false
},
  ]

  $scope.select=-1;

    $scope.add=function(task,description){
      if ($scope.tasks.indexOf(task)!== -1){
        this.list="Already exists!"
      }
else{
  newtask={
    taskname: task,
    description: description,
    selected: false
  };

  $scope.tasks.push(newtask);

    }
  };

$scope.delete=function(task){
  var index = $scope.tasks.indexOf(task);
  $scope.tasks.splice(index, 1);

}


});
```

Comment: Have you tried using [ion-button](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/button/Button/)

Comment: yes, doenst work either. Its like something is over the button and i cant click it, if i put the button outside the ng-repeat i can click it.

Comment: I would try doing the no-repeat on ion-item not on the list directive itself like the docs.

Comment: Still can't click it. I dont know what might be the issue

Comment: Try setting the z-index on the class of those buttons to 1000. It's not the right way but it will tell us if it is because of some styling from ionic.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller line should be:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$ionicModal', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
```

And obviously the extra ] at the end.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i still can not click the gear button. Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried just using <button> instead of the <ion... see if the button works then.

Comment: No, doesnt work. It seems that the list is over the button and thats why i cant click it. I dont know how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

I removed the ios-list and ion-item tags and replace them with the ul and li ones and it worked perfectly, is there something wrong with those tags?